# HTML draughts/checkers game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on creating a draughts/checkers game in HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I have utilised drag and drop to allow the pieces to move around the board. all this code does at the moment is create a board and allow the pieces to be moved to any white squares.

I am unsure on how to add the part where pieces are removed from the board when they have been jumped over by one of the opposing teams pieces. does anyone know how to implement this?

This is my code so far:

```css
.draughtboard {
width: 640px;
height: 640px;
margin: 2px;
border: 3px solid black;
}

.black, .white {
float: left;
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
font-size: 60px;
text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.black {
background-color: black;
}

.white {
background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<title>Draughts</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div style="padding: 1px">
Player 1 pieces: <p id="p1card">12</p> // Player 2 pieces: <p id="p2card">12</p>
</div>
<div class="draughtboard">

<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div1"></div><img id="drag1" src="blackPiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div2"></div><img id="drag2" src="blackPiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div3"></div><img id="drag3" src="blackPiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div4"></div><img id="drag4" src="blackPiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>

<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div5"></div><img id="drag5" src="blackPiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div6"></div><img id="drag6" src="blackPiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div7"></div><img id="drag7" src="blackPiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div8"></div><img id="drag8" src="blackPiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>

<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div9"></div><img id="drag9" src="blackPiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div10"></div><img id="drag10" src="blackPiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div11"></div><img id="drag11" src="blackPiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div12"></div><img id="drag12" src="blackPiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>

<div class="black"></div>
<div id="div13" ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div class="white"></div></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div id="div14" ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div class="white"></div></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div id="div15" ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div class="white"></div></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div id="div16" ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div class="white"></div></div>

<div id="div17" ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div class="white"></div></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div id="div18" ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div class="white"></div></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div id="div19" ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div class="white"></div></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div id="div20" ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div class="white"></div></div>
<div class="black"></div>

<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div21"></div><img id="drag13" src="whitePiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div22"></div><img id="drag14" src="whitePiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div23"></div><img id="drag15" src="whitePiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div24"></div><img id="drag16" src="whitePiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>

<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div25"></div><img id="drag17" src="whitePiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div26"></div><img id="drag18" src="whitePiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div27"></div><img id="drag19" src="whitePiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div28"></div><img id="drag20" src="whitePiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>

<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div29"></div><img id="drag21" src="whitePiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div30"></div><img id="drag22" src="whitePiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div31"></div><img id="drag23" src="whitePiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="div32"></div><img id="drag24" src="whitePiece.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="80" height="80"></div>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev){
 ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev){
 ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev){
 ev.preventDefault();
 var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
 ev.traget.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
```

Comment: First you need to limit the player to only move one square at a time, and even then only in the forward direction (worry about "kinging"/backward later). Once you've got this system of "valid drop squares", it shouldn't be too difficult to check if that drop square is occupied by an opponent, and if so then check the next square beyond it to see if capture is possible.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I understand what you are saying and I see how this would fix it. however I don't know how I would create this limit to only let the pieces move one square, I'm still trying to learn JavaScript fully so my knowledge of it is lacking but I need to get this done ASAP.

Comment: You will need to keep track of where the piece currently is, and where the player is trying to move it to, and respond accordingly if it's a valid move.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I don't know how to actually do what you are suggesting in code form. I can think of how you are suggesting to do it but don't know what code would make that happen, like I said I'm not the best with JavaScript.